# My update statement in postgresql runs for more than 1 hour when updating using a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery

I have a dataset and it has some missing values. It is a time series dataset so I want to update the missing values with the value from the previous day.

I created a view that contains the lag of the value of the two previous days. See below:

| sale_date | daily_op | lag_op1 | lag_op2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-01-03 | 92.97 | 93.14 | null |
| 2013-01-04 | 93.12 | 92.97 | 93.14 |
| 2013-01-05 | null | 93.12 | 92.97 |

My main table contains 3 million records and I want to use the view with the lagged op variables to impute the missing values in my main table.

I ran this code:

```sql
update wholetest
   set daily_op = (select lag_op1 from lag_op where lag_op.sale_date = wholetest.sale_date)
   where daily_op is null;
```

And it was taking a while so I ran to target and I came back and it was still running. It had a run time of more than 1 hour, so I don't think it is working correctly even if it has a lot of records.

I tried adding the 'limit 1' option after wholetest.sale_date but that did not seem to work. (i.e. the view with the lagged variables has one distinct date). Please let me know what I am doing wrong with my code.

Comment: Why save a value that is dependent on other data when it can be retrieved in query when needed? Correlated subqueries are known to perform slowly. Did the query ever finish and was data saved correctly?

Comment: Wait, daily_op should be the collected saved data and the two lag fields should be calculated? Why is daily_op null?

Comment: *"I created a view"* is a bit on the fuzzy side for a view definition. Even less clear: your version of Postgres, or whether `sale_date` is defined unique with an index or constraint enforcing that. And is there concurrent write access? All of that would help more than knowledge about your shopping habits.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a **unique index** (or PK) on `wholetest.sale_date`? Else you might get arbitrary results - at added cost proportional to the number of duplicates. In other words: expensive nonsense.

With said unique index, the query should be fast - well a table with 3 million rows will take a couple seconds. (We can assume that most rows don't need an update?!) Unless you messed up your undisclosed view. Either way, you shouldn't need a view for this. Just:

```sql
UPDATE wholetest w
SET    daily_op = (
   SELECT daily_op
   FROM   wholetest w1
   WHERE  w1.sale_date < w.sale_date
   ORDER  BY w1.sale_date DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
WHERE w.daily_op IS NULL;
```

If you have consecutive entries with null values, you need to do more.

The only other thing (besides breakage or serious contention for storage, RAM and/or CPU) would be locking issues. Typically concurrent writes to the tables in long running transactions. Check the system view `pg_stat_activity` in this case. See:

- [Estimate end time for a long update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125202/3684)

Comment: I cannot use a unique index for date because each date has a corresponding 54 store numbers and 33 departments for each store number. I ran the code that you have given me and there is no error but it still ran for more than 2 hours this time. Is your code contingent on having a unique index? Also, unrelated, what does the w and w1 do/mean?

Comment: `w` and `w1` are table [aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html). For anything more, please [edit]  your question with the requested information.